# How to split an array value?

Tags: php

In my array I have these values:

```
[10d, 10e] => 4
```

The values are retrieved from another website and the important values will be put in this array.
Now I want to have two single values from these like:

```
[10d] => 2 [10e] => 2
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What if numeric value is 3?

Comment: @Kyslik or what is it was 3 entries with value of 2

Comment: Are those "array values" strings or what? php does not offer real multi dimensional arrays...

Comment: @onetrickpony - The value should be divided by 2.

Comment: @Kyslik - the value is always divisible by 2.

Comment: in case we are talking about float values yes 3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I'm guessing a little because of the description that is not that clear.

```
$arr = array('10d, 10e' => 4);
$newArr = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    $newKeys = explode(',', $key);
    foreach($newKeys as $item) {
        $newArr[trim($item)] = $value / count($newKeys);
    }
}
print_r($newArr);
```

Result
`[10d] => 2 [10e] => 2`

Comment: @Prix correct me if I'm wrong but `explode(',', $var)` on a string without a comma will return an array with a single key item, so it will work without checking for a comma.

Comment: @Prix It doesn't fail on entries with single data for me atleast.

Answer (score 0):

Some functions you can use:

- [foreach()](http://php.net/foreach) to loop the input array
- [explode()](http://php.net/explode) to split the key
- [trim()](http://php.net/trim) to remove whitespace
- [count()](http://php.net/count) to, well, count array items
- And, of course, [/](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) to divide ;-)